# Android Studio - Text size problem across multiple devices

Tags: android, android-studio, text, size

So I have read possibly everything about the difference between **sp** and **dp**. I can say that I do understand why sp is better than dp regarding text size. One thing I don't understand and want some help with is how do I make the text look the same with every possible font size the user has selected for their phone? Is it that bad to use dp for text size? (I know that the app won't take the user's phone font size into consideration but at least it will look the same across the board.) Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is not bad at all to use DP as text size. It just won't follow the users preferences regarding text size. We have to use the tools we have, to best fit our needs. I always use DP in elements wich i need to maintain the layout. If you don't want the text size to change, use DP. Some times i use [textAutosizing](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview) When the text changes. And often i use sp, when dealing with "content" text, wich can grow and scroll, shrink and fit.

Comment: Yeah, I just wanted to ask because on literally every post about this across multiple sites people were saying that you should use dp for text only in extreme cases and you should stay away from it most of the time. That just seemed strange to me and that's why I asked this question.

Answer (score 3):

To make the text look the same irrespective of the users' choice, use dp. To change the text size according to users' choice use sp. So, if you have a constraint that the text size should remain the same use dp.